# Extracting separate co-ordinates of a game object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently working on a school project where I'll be using motion capture and unity. It's made for the elderly to improve their cognitive and motoric functions. I want unity to be able to record their movements into a CSV file to see how well they are doing. I want the x, y and z co-ordinate recorded against time in excel.

I'm using perception neuron for my motion capture which has a total of 32 sensors. The 3D model in unity has 32 different parts/limbs that move, including the fingers. I added a picture of it here:

[image]

Now in this code, I can't seem to get the coordinates of a limb (i'm just trying to get the coordinates of a single limb for now). I struggling with trying to extract the gameobject's coordinates. But I tried splitting Vector3 into x, y, z coordinates to get separate coordinates and also because I want the values to be float too but it does not seem to work could anyone help me with this?

Here's my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using System.IO;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    float timer = 100.0f;
    public TestSO so ;
    StreamWriter motionData;



    public void Start()
    {
        string fullFilename = @"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\CsvPlz.csv";

        motionData = new StreamWriter(fullFilename, true);

        InvokeRepeating("wolf", 0.0f, 0.5f);
    }

    void wolf()
    {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
        string delimiter = ", ";

        var position : Vector3;

        var x: float = position[0];
        var y : float = position[1];
        var z : float = position[2];

        if (timer > 1.0f)
        {
            timer -= 1.0f;            
            string dataText = ("{1}",x) + delimiter + ("{2}", y) + delimiter + ("{3}", z);
            motionData.WriteLine(dataText);
        }

        motionData.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not initializing position: you should initialize it with the limb's position. Am I right?

Comment: It looks like you'er mixing C# with Javascript(Unityscript) by the way you declared the local variables in `the wolf` function. You can't use both languages in one script. You have to use one.

Comment: Oh thats probably because i used sample codes from 2 different places and i tried to merge them to make my own. I didn't realize it had java script, is it a problem though? do i have remove the java script part?

Comment: and also how do i intialize the limbs position?

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
var position : Vector3;

var x: float = position[0];
var y : float = position[1];
var z : float = position[2];
```

To

```
Vector3 position = Vector3.One;

float x = position.x;
float y = position.y;
float z = position.z;
```

the variables x y and z are optional, as Vector3 already contains floats. You could just use position.x directly.